# FOL: Translation of sentences into logical proposition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

> Translate the following sentences into wfs.

John hates all people who do not hate themselves.

Let O:= hate themselve, h:=John hates.

Then $\forall x ( \lnot O(x) \to h(x) )$

Is this translation correct?

Also, for this sentence

*Any sets that have the same members are equal*,

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

For the first one you want to use a 2-place predicate $H(x,y)$ that stands for '$x$ hates $y$'

for the second one, use a 2-place predicate $x \in y$ that expresses that $x$ is an element of $y$

Comment: For the second one,  $H(x,y):=x$ is an element of $y$. $\forall x \forall y (H(x,y) \iff H(y,x))$ this would be correct answer?

Comment: @Michelle No. If you translate that back into English you get that '$x$ is an element of $y$ if and only if $y$ is an element of $x$'.  ... which makes little sense: $1$ is an element of the set if natural numbers, but the set of natural numbers is of course not an element of $1$. Instead, use the $x$ and $y$ for the two sets, but use a third variable $z$ to talk about the members of those sets. So try again. Also, do you have another attempt for the first one?

Comment: ok, for the first one would be $\forall x (\lnot H(x,x)\to H(J,x))$, where J is for John so it shouldn't be quantified right?

Comment: @Michelle Yes, that's exactly it! :)

Comment: For the second one, let $H(z,X)=z$ is an element of the set X, then $\forall z\forall X\forall Y (H(z,X)\iff H(z,Y))$, is it correct ?

Comment: @Michelle You're close. The $\forall z (H(z,x) \leftrightarrow H(z,y))$ component ends up saying that $x$ and $y$ have the same members. but by putting the $\forall x \forall y$ in front of it, you end up saying that 'every two sets have the same members' ... which is clearly not true. In stead, thnk of the sentence as expressing a condition: *if* two sets have the same members, then they are equal. So try again.

Comment: yes the 'then x=y' is missed, $\forall z [(H(z,x) \leftrightarrow H(z,y))\to x=y]$

Comment: but I think it's wrong, the = should not appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68952/discussion-between-bram28-and-michelle).

Comment: @Michelle Yes, you *do* have to use $x=y$. But ypu also need to quantify the $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $(\forall z [(H(z,x) \leftrightarrow H(z,y))])\to \forall x\forall y (x=y)$ is it correct?

Comment: @Michelle No. remember that references to a variable need to occur *within* the scope of their quantifier. So, move the $\forall x $ and $\forall y$ to the front.

Comment: $\forall x\forall y( \forall z [(H(z,x) \leftrightarrow H(z,y))])\to  (x=y) )$ now?

Comment: @Michelle Yes! ... though you have one fewer opening parenthesis '(' than closing parentheses ')' ...